# Grant access to SSRS but not SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012

I am the administrator/owner of a SSMS database.  I have a number of users that use the report manager (SSRS) for reporting purposes.  What I want to prevent is them from downloading SQL Server Management Studio and accessing the entire database. How do I configure the permissions to allow access to Reporting Services but not Management Studio?

On a similar note, is there a way to grant read only permissions to certain tables in SSMS?  Like if I want a user to have the ability to query only certain tables.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: SSMS is just a tool, you cannot prevent downloading it. At least not in a free world  :)

Comment: Move SSRS to a dedicated server with limited set of credentials. Restrict access to DB server only from the new SSRS server using Windows tools. Give access to SSRS server to users via browser in read-only mode.

Comment: Set your permissions on the database and limit them accordingly for the user's login.

Comment: The users do not have to have access to the database. You can configure the DataSources of your reports to use specific credentials that are used to access the database (do this in "Report Manager" which btw. was renamed to "Report Server Portal" some years ago).